# Joomla (Add New Contact Parameters to Contact in Jooma1.5)

Tags: joomla, parameters, joomla1.5, contacts

I am New to Joomla and this is my First Project I am working on in JOOMLA
Well I have Template Named News Line by Youjoomla ( Most of you Might Have heard about it)

here is my Questions
Well My Client gave me a sudden change in the requirement that he needs some additional parameters in a every contact

Which are Like
Registration Number
Company Name 
and More.....

Well Can Anybudy Teach me how to add new parameters to contact in Joomla 1.5
it is a Little Bit Urgent

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default Joomla contact system then adding custom parameters is rather hard. You will be better off using a Contact Component such as [aiContactSafe](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms/7901). You can find more [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms) aswell. Hope this helps and good luck with your first Joomla project

Comment: Well I think You got me Wrong Sir
Actually I dont want more parameters in a contact form 
I want a Few more parameters in the contact us details in which we have

Name      Position       Email      Phone Number       Web URL

to these parameters  want to add a few more things like Registration Number, Company Name, Contact Person   Like That

http://www.joomlatemplates.youjoomla.info/newsline/index.php?option=com_contact&view=category&Itemid=3

Please see this page 
we have contact us details I need the same format but with a few more parameters

I have the same template with me

Comment: but with aiContactSafe, you can achieve this ;)